# How to set Multiple bool flags based on an int counter without iterating?

Tags: c#

What is the best way to set my `boolean` properties based on an `int` counter property?

So, lets say I have 10 boolean properties

```
public bool IsBool1 {get;set;}
....
public bool IsBool10 {get;set;}
```

and an int counter **(which can never have a value greater than 10)**

```
public int Counter {get;set;}
```

Finally, I have a method which sets the flags

```
private void SetFlagsByCounter(int counter)
{
  if (counter >= 1) { IsBool1 = true; }
  .....
  if (counter >= 10) { IsBool10 = true; }
}
```

Is there a better way to set the flags instead of iterating the counter?

Comment: Suggestion:  IsBool1 is a bit hard to read.  Lowercase L vs. number 1 thing ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you actually *need* to have the 10 auto-properties? Could you have 10 properties which just return a value based on the counter? (Do you even need 10 properties in the first place?)

For example:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Counter { get; set; }

    public bool IsBool1 { get { return Counter >= 1; } }
    public bool IsBool2 { get { return Counter >= 2; } }
    public bool IsBool3 { get { return Counter >= 3; } }
    public bool IsBool4 { get { return Counter >= 4; } }
    ...
}
```

Note that this differs from your original in 3 ways:

- There's no `SetFlagsByCounter` method, just the property
- In the original, if you called `SetFlagsByCounter(10)` and then `SetFlagsByCounter(1)`, then IsBool5 (etc) would still return true, because you never cleared the flags.
- In the original, `SetFlagsByCounter` didn't use (or change) the `Counter` property at all, in the code shown.

If you could give more context, it would be easier to help you.

Comment: Thanks, checking flags based on the Counter right in the property seems like a good solution. I am almost certain that we can do without 10 auto properties, however the asp.net page is making use of these properties and I don't have the time to go in and fix/optimize and then test the code which someone else has written - however I just didn't like how these flags were being set, hence I asked :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you just use properties for the booleans?

```
public bool IsBool1
{
    get
    {
        return counter >= 1;
    }
}

public bool IsBool2
{
    get
    {
        return counter >= 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: This fails the OP's requirements.  You need to capture greater than data as well

Comment: @Woot: Yes but that doesn't hurt the general idea of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If after all you still need to have 10 `bool` properties and a `SetFlagsByCounter` method, then the way to do it would be to define an internal array of `bool` as a backing value for the properties, like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    bool flags[] = new flags[10];

    public bool IsBool1 { get { return flags[0]; } set { flags[0] = value; } }
    public bool IsBool2 { get { return flags[1]; } set { flags[1] = value; } }
    ...
    public bool IsBool10 { get { return flags[9]; } set { flags[9] = value; } }

    public void SetFlagsByCounter(int counter)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        {
            flags[i] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `SetFlagsByCounter` method needs to also set the rest of the flags `false`.  Alternatively, loop over the entire set and use `i <= counter` instead of `true`.

Comment: @Steve Townsend: I left this functionality out on purpose - because the original code in the question didn't do it as well... His code only ever sets the flags to `true` and never to `false` and I just duplicated the same behavior. I felt like giving a direct answer for a change instead of trying to explain why the question is wrong...:)

Comment: The question is not wrong. I don't want to clear the flags when setting one of them. The counter basically is saying something like that I have 3 objects, so set the 3 flags. Makes sense?